# WSO2 WSAS Application Server and ELB not working

Tags: proxy, wso2, load-balancing, wso2-esb

I succesfully followed the guides on http://docs.wso2.org/display/Cluster/Clustering+Application+Server and have deployed an scenario of one ELB 2.1.0 balancing and connecting the nodes as follows:
 - One machine with the ELB, Manager and Worker node
 - Another physical different machine with another worker node

All the managing on the ELB and manager and workers seems to be fine, for the logs and the console show every member connecting to each other, and so.

My problem is that if I configure the "proxyPort" properties on the Catalina-server.xml of the Manager and the workers node, I can't connect trhough the ports on the ELB 8280 or 8243, because I am obtaining a blank page (if i try to use the manager administration console) or a blank webserver response (if I try to consume any webservice through the ELB port).

If I don't configure the proxyPorts properties on each node, and point to each IP and port separately, I can successfully use the manager console, and consume the WebServices on each worker node as I expected but...of course, this way I am not having Load Balance and High Availability.

Sorry to bother you because I'm new at this matters, but I searched the internet all around and have found how to fix problems all the way through this point I'm in... It seems that the problem should only be at some transportation level configuration on the axis2.xml of some node, or maybe the fact our network is behind a proxy had something to be...don't know.

¿Anybody could give any advice? Versions are: WSAS 5.2.0 and ELB 2.1.0.

We have found now, that working with previous versions (with Tribes and not Hazelcast as the clustering class), WSAS 5.1.0 and ELB 2.0.3, and not changing the parameter  on the Axis2.xml file in the ELB (leaving as it comes, being different than the domain established in the loadbalancer.cfg and the domain in the Axis2.xml of the Workers and Managers), it works well. But, if we don't change the  on the axis2.xml working with the 5.2.0 and 2.1.0 versions, trying to replicate the status we have with the previous version, the ELB doesn't realice that a manager and worker are connecting to him (we can't see anything on the ELB logs when launching the manager and Worker), so I suppose in this case the clustering is not working, and for it to work properly, we need to set the  in the Axis2.xml of the loadbalancer the same as in the loadbalancer.conf and in the axis2.xml of the rest of nodes in the cluster.

We need to deploy this for testing and valoration purposes on a customer and we would like to understand or to know if there is something wrong with the last versions, or this is just a lack of knowledge for our part, case when we will need the help of this forum :).

In this link you could find the configuration files involved in the ELB 2.1.0 and Manager WSAS 5.2.0 issue: http://www.dravencrow.com/varios/configuration_files.rar

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: This could be a configuration issue in your environment. You just need to map the host names of Application Server management and worker to ELB IP. Proxy ports of Application Server should be the corresponding ports of ELB. May be you can send all the relevant configs to our dev@ mailing list and we can check. wso2.org/mail

Comment: Thanks Isuru. I'm trying to register on the wso2 mail list and as soon as I can I would put the information on my .cfg's there. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited the first message adding a link to the configuration files and explaining a new test case: It seems that with previous versions of ELB and WSAS, not changing the domain on the axis2.xml at ELB level, it works well. Puting the same domain in this file (needed to make the cluster nodes seeing each other in last versions) as the domain configured in the loadbalancer.conf, makes the blank page issue happens. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi again. Just for the sake of others with the same problem, we finally worked this out.<br>f

Comment: Hi Draven, I'm really sorry for the delay. I'm glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of others with the same problem, we finally worked this out.
 
It seems that with the newest versions of ELB (2.1.0) you need to stablish the port where to listen to other members in the "loadbalancer.conf" level, with the property "group_mgt_port", which did not comes as default in the file from the release of ELB 2.1.0.
 Also, the domain fixed in the Axis2.xml of the ELB level must be totally different from the domain fixed in the rest of Axis2.xml files of other nodes (and from the domain in the loadbalancer.conf itself).
 With this setup, the last version of ELB and AS works fine taking care of connections between each other, and the proxyports works as well connecting to manager and workers throug the elb port 8243. 
Thank you very much for your patience and apologies for bothering you....it's really difficult find some reliable documentation on the last versions of each product in the WSO2 suite, for the most of the info available is spreaded through different blogs and forums. Regards

Comment: Hi Draven, with Carbon 4.2.0, Hazelcast based clustering was introduced and that's why the group_mgt_port property was introduced. Domain is used to identify the cluster. That's why you need different domains for different products. The domain also maps with the configs in your loadbalancer.conf. Please post if you have further questions and in the mean time we will try to get the Wiki docs updated as soon as possible.

Comment: Did you refer this? http://docs.wso2.org/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+Application+Server

Comment: Hi Isuru. Yes, thank you...I had found that but, at first instance it doesn't works, so I started to follow another forums and blogs in the WSO2 "cloud" with previous configurations on prior version, and messed with all the configuration files until I get the cluster to work mixing instructions from here and there...and then I get to the problems with ProxyPort and the Explorer sending me a blank page, and lost the perspective. My bad, absolutely.

Comment: Now that I have it Working, the only thing I found different from that appears on the documentation, is that I'm not accesing the manager console through:  
https://mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com:9444/carbon, but through the port 8243 of the ELB (configured in the proxyport in the Catalina-server).... ¿Am I missing any other thing? Really thank you.

Comment: In your configuration, the management node cluster is also accessed via ELB. That is why you need ELB port. ELB recognizes the cluster via the hostname, in this case "mgt.as.cloud-test.wso2.com". Since you added the proxy port for management node, you can only access it via the ELB.

Comment: That was what I suppose, so...really thank you, Isuru :). It's being quite hard to start with WSAS and ESB without having access to the support options (this will be valorated later, when we can show to our customers the different products of WSO2 installed and serving basic requests). Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Again, Isuru. Doing and testing everything as commanded on the docs founded under the wso2 online docs works ok...until I add another worker node on a different machine (that is the purpose of clustering, I suppose ;-)). The second node (I couldn't found a guide on adding a second node with AS 5.2 and ELB 2.1), joins the cluster but starts to unjoin and rejoin every few seconds...and when it exits the cluster, leaves it all malfunctioning (no SOA request are handled throug ELB ports). With only one node, everything is fine, but the second one messes it up...¿Any clues on this behaviour?

Comment: Hi, That's strange! Yes, adding another worker should work without any problem. :) These products are released only after comprehensive testing in QA, which includes clustered setup in different nodes. Do you have any network issues in the nodes? Could you please confirm that everything is okay in your environment. I hope you are using wka membership scheme. I think you can send a mail to dev@ list with configurations and someone will reply. :) http://wso2.com/mail/